# Tracking Unsuccessful delivery reports in sending bulk Emails

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about Unsuccessful delivery reports in sending bulk Emails.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847985/question-about-unsuccessful-delivery-reports-in-sending-bulk-emails)

Hello all, I have database of approximately 10k users who have subscribed for newsletters. I am changing my site from asp to php. I am sending newsletters by cron job. I want to track the record of unsuccessful delivery report. How is it possible? Please Guide me, Thanks.